# Problem with useState from React, too many re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar library for a small project of notes 'to do', just for learn React js (I'm new to that). When I take the data from realtime database on firebase, I try to show into the calendar the name of the event (evento) and the date (fecha), but when I use setName() for put the data and save it into the array `name=[]`, then through me a error like re-render, and I don't know how to fix it.... if any one can help me, its will be great!!

(and sorry for my bad English)

Thanks

Here is the error and the code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5NKa.png)

```
    const [date, SetFecha] = useContext(Contexto)
    const [name, setName] = useState([])

    firebase.database().ref().on('value', (snapshot) => {
        let obj = snapshot.val()
        Object.values(obj.Notas).forEach(e => {
            setName([...name, { title: e.evento, date: e.fecha }])
        });
    })



    const DateClick = (arg) => {
        SetFecha(arg.dateStr)    
    }

    return (
        <FullCalendar
            plugins={[dayGridPlugin, listPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
            initialView="dayGridMonth"

            dateClick={DateClick}
            events={name} 
        />
    )
```

**SOLUTION**

```
 useEffect(() => {
        firebase.database().ref().on('value', (snapshot) => {
            let obj = snapshot.val()
            let arr = []
            Object.values(obj.Notas).forEach(e => {
                arr.push({ title: e.evento, date: e.fecha })
            });
            setName(arr)
        })
    }, []);
```

Comment: You are setting the state in a forEach() loop and you cannot do that as it is asynchronous  which will conflict the different states available on each iteration. What you can do is to create an array and push ```[...name, { title: e.evento, date: e.fecha }]``` to it. Then outside of the forEach() you ```setName(array)```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `useEffect` hook. Try something like:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.database().ref().on('value', (snapshot) => {
      const obj = snapshot.val();
      const arrData = [];
      Object.values(obj.Notas).forEach(e => 
        arrData.push({ title: e.evento, date: e.fecha }));
      setName(arrData);
    });
  }, firebase.database().ref().on('value'));
```

The issue in the above code you shown is that everytime you call `setName()`, the component is re-rendered (It is a special function returned by React to change the component state and re-render). And when it re-renders, the `setName()` is called again, thus causing an infinite loop in the re-rendering.

`useEffect()` is not run in re-render, but run only when detecting that data has changed. In this case, it checks if `firebase.database().ref().on('value')` has changed, and if yes, run the code in `useEffect()` and re-render.

More can be read [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Btw, there is a minor optimization can be applied is to use a local variable to store the value in process. And then call `setName()` only once. Because as mentioned, every time this special function is called, it
may cause re-render. So you want to call it only once when you have finished all the intermediate process. Or better, do it in a functional style:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.database().ref().on('value', (snapshot) => {
      setName(Object.values(snapshot.val().Notas).map(e => 
        { title: e.evento, date: e.fecha }));
    });
  }, firebase.database().ref().on('value'));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i can fix it with the firts code you pass, but i chanche `setName()` outside the `firebase.database().ref().on()...`, but obiusly inside the useEffect hook.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problem:

1. The firebase creates listener inside react component.
2. call setName inside `Array.prototype.forEach`;

I'll show you where is loop.

1. Component is rendered;
2. Component creates state `[name, setName]`;
3. Component calls `firebase.database().ref().on('value', callback)`;
4. Callback gets data from firebase and iterates by keys via forEach;
5. At the first iteration inside forEach you call `setName`;
6. `setName` calls re-render;
7. go to the `3` step;

**Solution:**

```js
function OwnComponent(props) {
  const [date, setFecha] = useContext(Contexto);
  const [name, setName] = useState([]);
    
  const dateClick = React.useCallback((arg) => {
    setFecha(arg.dateStr);
  }, [setFecha]);
    
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.database().ref(/* you can pass 'Notas' 
 here */).on('value', (snapshot) => {
      setName(Object.values(snapshot.val().Notas/* you can remove .Notas here */).map(
        ({ evento: title, fecha: date }) => ({ title, date })
      ));
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
    
  return (
    <FullCalendar
      plugins={[dayGridPlugin, listPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
      initialView="dayGridMonth"
      dateClick={dateClick}
      events={name} 
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer!! i can fix it!